# Laravel does not display my errors correctly

Tags: php, laravel

I've a little problem with Laravel, i'm displaying my errors like that :

```
{!! $errors->first('email', '<small class="help-block">:message</small>') !!}
```

But the error I get is : `validation.unique`

Do you know the reason ? Is it because i must to write all errors by myself ?

Thanks by advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you need just error message then you do not need to pass additional field. `:message`

You can do it by just passing column name.

```
{{ $errors->first('email') }}
```

[Laravel validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#retrieving-the-first-error-message-for-a-field)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
@if($errors->has('email'))
   {{ $errors->first('email') }}
@endif
```

Comment: no it's the same but now i understand, i'ts because i've loaded a lang file who does not exist.. lol thank you guys,  sorry i'm a beginner with Laravel ;)